why we need use covarience matrix to calculate eigenvectors and eigenvalues in pca
I am stuck at understanding the idea behind using covariance matrix for calculating eigenvectors and eigenvalues and select the eigenvector which has highest eigenvalue

If you use SVD, you don’t need the covariance matrix to do PCA. If you have a different question, you should [edit] to clarify what it is that you know and where you are stuck.
